# How can I set front camera as default in camera intent

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am using camera intent for capturing selfie but by default it open back camera and I want front camera by default.

```
ContentValues values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line:

```
cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1)
```

Although, it doesn't seem to always work. But it's the best you can get using just intents.